# Using the Multi Tenant feature to configure permissions

Tags: permissions, alfresco, multi-tenant

I want to make access polices on the folder each of costumer:

```
DocumentLibrary/Custumers/CostmerA
DocumentLibrary/Custumers/CostmerA
.
DocumentLibrary/Custumers/CostmerN
```

Then the `CustomerA` (tenant user) can't access the folders of other another Customers

I think abut doing this using "Tenants", and a would like to see an exeample.

Answer (score 2):

The Multi Tenant (MT) feature in Alfresco does not do what you ask for. Especially, tenants don't share the same document library, they are completely separated.

You *could* use MT to achieve complete separation of tenants. This separation would include not only documents but users, groups, permissions, everything you deploy in the Data Dictionary.

I recommend to use a single (default) tenant and normal folder permissions if you just want to handle read/write permissions.

Comment: Hi, I understand, but i'm thinking to use MT for to avoid the external access my structure. It's more securitty. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can use MT to separate customers completely. If that is what you want, go ahead :)

Answer (score 2):

Before using Multi-Tenancy, pay close attention to the features you will be giving up, which are documented [here](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/mt-not-implemented.html).

The correct way to do what you are attempting to do is to simply use permissions. Give all of your customers access to the /customers folder. Then, in each customer-specific folder, break the ACL inheritance (Manage Permissions, Un-check Inherit Permissions), then assign the specific customer (perhaps using a group) to the folder with the appropriate access.

You might even consider using a separate Share site for each customer, which would make this easier.

The caveat to this is that if you are trying to hide all of your users and groups from each other, then really what you want are separate repositories, and that's what Multi-Tenancy provides, at the expense of the features I referenced at the top of the post.

If you go that route, you'll have to use the tenant console to create each customer-specific tenant. Your tenants will be separated into their own repositories. And you won't have a way to view all of your customer documents side-by-side without switching tenants.

Honestly, due to the stability of the multi-tenancy feature and the other features you have to give up, I'd be more inclined to use completely separate servers, even though that increases your maintenance burden. Alfresco doesn't even use their own multi-tenancy feature in their own cloud product.

Answer (score 1):

You really should have no problems. MT is already there, you just need to enable it. There's no additional work that you should do in order to hide tenants from each others - that's the whole point of this feature.

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/mt-intro.html

Comment: How is it ? I have to create a second structure e to link with my tenants ? How will be the synchronization between structures ?